# How does space complexity and time complexity work in the following scenario?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Pardon as I am not much familiar with either Space complexity or time complexity.

My question is,

Imagine there is a piece of code in Java which will read a file which is a .csv and then print each line into a .txt as the output.

As I understood, time complexity somewhat depends on the number of lines.
And the space complexity is how much space it would take at the runtime.
(Please brief me up if this is wrong)

So as mentioned above,
if I did the code which would take all the lines in the input.csv at once to some sort of a data structure, then print the whole thing into the output.txt using the same data structure, would it get me a worse space complexity but a better time complexity?
Also,
If I read line by line and printed them onto the output.txt inside the same loop, would it give me a better space complexity but a worse time complexity?

Please do let me know if the question is not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A CSV file is already a text file, so your algorithm essentially just copies a text file to another file. The running time for any sensible algorithm which does this is O(n), and the space complexity of your algorithm is also O(n) because you load the whole file into memory. If you instead copy piece-by-piece then the space complexity would be O(1), assuming the pieces have a fixed size (e.g. using a fixed-size buffer).

Comment: The total *time* depends on the size of the input, the time *complexity* is a measure of how much time it takes given the size of the input, so that remains the same (the only dependence is on the algorithm, not the input, except when we distinguish between best, worst and average case). In practice, you usually care more about actual running time than complexity, since an O(n) algorithm that triggers a lot of garbage collection may be quite a bit worse than an O(n^2) algorithm that doesn't (for example), which is not something a traditional complexity analysis includes.

Answer (score 2):

Space complexity and time complexity are properties of *algorithms*.

In terms of space complexity, if you read a line and then print a line, then you need space to store the line as part of the algorithm.  That depends on the maximum length of a line.  I suppose that the input file could be one line.  So, this approach would have a space complexity of O(n), where "n" is the size of the input file, or the longest line in the file.

By contrast, reading all the data into memory would presumably have a space complexity of O(n).  However, the data structure could matter, and that might multiply it out.

On the other hand, reading the CSV file one character at a time and then writing that character would use constant space -- whatever is needed to store a single character.

As for time complexity, presumably work is done to read each character and then write it out, so the time would seem to be O(n).  However, if the data is stored in memory in a complex data structure, this could also be larger.

Answer (score 2):

> As I understood, time complexity somewhat depends on the number of lines.
> And the space complexity is how much space it would take at the runtime.

That is basically correct. Your time is going to be linear with the input, because you are going to process all of the input once and only once because you're not doing any magic like major transformations and so on. That said, if you process the input inefficiently, you could introduce significant overhead timewise, but that's still O(size of input).

Your space assumption is correct: how much are you going to use at once? Are you going to use a fraction of that (e.g. a single character), a portion (e.g. a line), a bit more (e.g. a buffer of some number of bytes), the whole thing (all lines, O(N)) or something more spacewise because you have to store additional state?

> if I did the code which would take all the lines in the input.csv at once to some sort of a data structure, then print the whole thing into the output.txt using the same data structure, would it get me a worse space complexity but a better time complexity?

This is likely to get you O(N) on space where N is the size of the input; you're storing the whole thing in memory. Your time complexity is a bit more complicated. On the face, your time is O(1): you write everything all at once. But it may be worse than that due to overhead and latency from marshalling data, engaging I/O and so on. Not easy to answer without more detail.

> If I read line by line and printed them onto the output.txt inside the same loop, would it give me a better space complexity but a worse time complexity?

Space, yes: your space would be O(average line size) instead of O(size of all input). But consider best and worst case scenarios. Worst case scenario O(# lines) for space = O(size of input) because there's only one line!